# What are the types of Homunculus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have been reading on the artificer class from D&D 3.5 an the class mentions that the artificer is not limited to the homunculus described in the monster manual. What i wish to ask is what types of homonculuses exist other than the monster manual one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game’s homunculi include the arbalester (*Magic of Eberron* 152), dedicated wright (*Eberron Campaign Setting* 285), expeditious messenger (*ECS* 285–6), furtive filcher (*ECS* 286), [homunculus](http://dndsrd.net/monstersHtoI.html#homunculus) (*Monster Manual* 154), iron defender (*ECS* 287), and packmate (*ME* 152–3).

So far as I'm aware, no other homunculi were published officially.